# Is it true that the CIA or the police has used mediums for remote viewing and clairvoyance while seeking missing persons?

Tags: police, cia

This [site](https://listverse.com/2021/01/29/top-10-things-you-probably-never-knew-about-witches/) claims that:

> Modern examples of clairvoyance are well known among mediums. Remote Viewing and clairvoyance have been used by the CIA and by the police when seeking missing persons

Is this claim true?

Comment: Other sources making similar claims: [1](https://youtu.be/L811nO601sg), [2](https://youtu.be/VQcHY2DUDd8), [3](https://youtu.be/hBl0cwyn5GY),  [4](https://youtu.be/zgyYms376Mg), [5](https://youtu.be/XMKE-vv5zSQ).

Comment: Well the CIA doesn't use psychics to find missing purposes, [because the CIA does not have any law enforcement ability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Intelligence_Agency).

Comment: Does [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43797/did-the-cia-conclude-that-uri-geller-had-psychic-powers/43798#43798) answer your question with regards to the CIA?  Every claim that I've seen with regards to the CIA goes back to project STARGATE in some fashion.

Comment: @DenisS Partly. What about the police in terms of missing persons.

Comment: @TheMaskedRebel if you search our site for "police psychics" you'll get a bunch of questions already asked on the site

Comment: This tends to tangle up the [Stargate Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Project) and [The Men who Stare at Goats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Men_Who_Stare_at_Goats) both of which involved other pars of the US intelligence and defense community

Comment: Such a wishy-washy claim. That they were *used* isn't evidence that they *work*. But related questions: [It isn't prevalent in the USA](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19495/does-any-police-emergancy-services-department-in-the-us-uk-australia-canada-empl) and [Scotland Yard doesn't use them](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10253/did-christopher-robinson-provide-psychic-information-that-was-successfully-used).

Comment: @DenisS: (1) what their charter says and what they have in fact done is far from identical, and (2) many non-law enforcement organizations have participated in searching for missing persons for various persons (private investigators do this frequently, for example).

Comment: A page on the CIA’s own website comes up as the first result when I search: https://www.cia.gov/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP96-00787R000200080025-7.pdf. :p

Comment: @Laurel the press cutting in your link ends with *"There is no indication that they have stopped, **and no reason why they would**"*.

Comment: "used by the CIA and by the police when seeking missing persons" can be parsed as "used by the CIA [for whatever purposes] and by the police when seeking missing persons". It doesn't really claim that *the CIA* used it to find it missing persons.